# dispatching started for transformation

Tags: pentaho, pdi

When I preview rows in Text file Input control of Pentaho, no rows appear and 'Show log' option displays this message

```
"Dispatching started for transformation".
```

What does it mean? How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that either your transformation is invalid (you're missing one essential checkbox or another) or your PDI installation isn't working properly.

Which JAVA version are you using? And which PDI version? Try it on a fresh install and if it still doesn't work, go over your text file input step and validate that it's correctly configured.

Also, try removing all other steps, it could be that one of the subsequent steps is the one causing problems and stopping PDI from starting the transformation execution.

Answer (score 0):

Well... maybe it's quite late, but I'm currently struggling with this issue in the Pentaho Community Version 8.

What I found, and solved some of my issues is that this message can be a potential warning for a Deadlock process. You have to be sure that none of this situations are present in your code:

1. An external component like a table lock by the database blocks the transformation.
2. The "Block this step until steps finish" step might run into a deadlock when there are more rows to process than the number of Rows in Rowset.
3. Within transformations there are situations when streams get split and joined again, so that the transformation blocks by design.

You could see full examples in the Jira Pentaho documentation page:

https://pentaho-community.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/EAI/pages/386807182/Transformation+Deadlocks

I hope that it will help you!